# Hangman Game Finding Duplicates

Tags: java, duplicates

So far I have got it find single characters and it even finishes with amount of guess and shows you the guessed word. But I cant get it finding duplicates :( any ideas guys.
Here's my code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Hangman
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    String tempGuess;
    char blank = '_';
    int amountOfGuesses = 0;


    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter A Word : ");
    String guessWord = k.nextLine();
    char[] myArray = guessWord.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.length(); i++)
    {
    myArray[i] = blank;
    }
    System.out.println(myArray);
    boolean whilerun = true;
    while (whilerun == true)
    {
        System.out.print("Please Guess A Letter : ");
        String guessLetter = k.nextLine();
        amountOfGuesses = amountOfGuesses + 1;
        int tempLG = guessWord.indexOf(guessLetter);

        if (tempLG == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("Character Not In  Word");
        }   
        else
        {


        myArray[tempLG] = guessWord.charAt(tempLG);

        }

       System.out.println(myArray);
       String tempGW = new String(myArray);
       if (tempGW.equalsIgnoreCase(guessWord))
       {
           whilerun = false;
       }

    }
    System.out.print("Well Done You Guessed The Word In " + amountOfGuesses + " trys.");

    }
}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Duplicate as in some guess that was already made?

Comment: Can you post the entire problem too?

Comment: Do you mean like if a word has two P's and the user guess is P, the program will the display two P's instead of one?

Answer (score 0):

Change your else statement to the following if you want the code to notify you on duplicate entries.

```
 else {
      String val = String.valueOf(myArray);
      if(val.contains(guessLetter)) {
          System.out.println("Char already found");
      }
      myArray[tempLG] = guessWord.charAt(tempLG);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/*
 * graphs - Hangman.java, Nov 18, 2013 6:08:55 PM
 * 
 */
import java.util.*;

/**
 * The Class Hangman.
 * 
 * @author Rajakrishna V. Reddy
 * @version 1.0
 *
 */
public class Hangman
{

```
/**
 * The main method.
 * 
 * @param args
 *            the arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String tempGuess;
    char blank = '_';
    int amountOfGuesses = 0;
    final Map<String, Integer> duplicateCharIndexMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter A Word : ");
    String guessWord = k.nextLine();
    char[] myArray = guessWord.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.length(); i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = blank;
    }
    System.out.println(myArray);
    boolean whilerun = true;
    while (whilerun)
    {
        System.out.print("Please Guess A Letter : ");
        String guessLetter = k.nextLine();
        amountOfGuesses = amountOfGuesses + 1;
        final int tempLG = guessWord.indexOf(guessLetter, duplicateCharIndexMap.get(guessLetter) == null ? 0
                : duplicateCharIndexMap.get(guessLetter));
        if (tempLG == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("Character Not In  Word");
        }
        else
        {
            duplicateCharIndexMap.put(guessLetter, tempLG + 1);
            myArray[tempLG] = guessWord.charAt(tempLG);
        }
        System.out.println(myArray);
        String tempGW = new String(myArray);
        if (tempGW.equalsIgnoreCase(guessWord))
        {
            whilerun = false;
        }

    }
    System.out.print("Well Done You Guessed The Word In " + amountOfGuesses + " trys.");
}
```

}

Comment: Just store the duplicate letters in map with indexes for next search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.hangman;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hangman
{

    /**
     * The main method.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            the arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String tempGuess;
        char blank = '_';
        int amountOfGuesses = 0;
        final Map<String, Integer> duplicateCharIndexMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please Enter A Word : ");
        String guessWord = k.nextLine();
        char[] myArray = guessWord.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.length(); i++)
        {
            myArray[i] = blank;
        }
        System.out.println(myArray);
        boolean whilerun = true;
        boolean duplicateFlag = false;
        while (whilerun)
        {
            duplicateFlag = true;
            System.out.print("Please Guess A Letter : ");
            String guessLetter = k.nextLine();
            amountOfGuesses = amountOfGuesses + 1;
            while (duplicateFlag)
            {
                final int tempLG = guessWord.indexOf(guessLetter, duplicateCharIndexMap.get(guessLetter) == null ? 0
                        : duplicateCharIndexMap.get(guessLetter));
                if (tempLG == -1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Character Not In  Word");
                    duplicateFlag = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    duplicateCharIndexMap.put(guessLetter, tempLG + 1);
                    myArray[tempLG] = guessWord.charAt(tempLG);
                }

            }

            System.out.println(myArray);
            String tempGW = new String(myArray);
            if (tempGW.equalsIgnoreCase(guessWord))
            {
                whilerun = false;
            }

        }
        System.out.print("Well Done You Guessed The Word In " + amountOfGuesses + " trys.");
    }
}
```